# IOS ad-hoc error “the app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified” when I switched to xcode new buildsystem

Tags: javascript, ios, react-native

I was using the xcode legacy build system to build a my react-native app. Then the app worked find. But Newly added third-party libraries require a new build system. Then I switched to xcode new build system.

After switching build system, ipa built by ad-hoc are not installed on the iPhone. And it generates “the app cannot be installed because its integrity could not be verified” error.

I'm using version 15 of x-code. Can anyone help?

Comment: Do you mean Xcode 12 with ios 15?

Comment: Oh, yes, that's correct.